# simple linker.ld file broke the executable MinGW

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, linker-scripts

I have tried a simple linker script in MinGW using the following commands 
`gcc -Wall  -c boot.c`
`ld boot.o -o boot.exe -T linker.ld`
`boot.c` contains

```
int my_main(void){
    return 0x1000;
}
```

`linker.ld` contains

```
ENTRY(my_main)
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    .bss : { *(.bss) }
}
```

the linker output is warning `warning: cannot find entry symbol my_main; defaulting to 00000000`
and the virtual addresses of the sections are weird values:

```
C:\src>objdump -h boot.exe

boot.exe:     file format pei-i386

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         0000000c  00000000  00000000  00000200  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .rdata        00000024  00001000  00001000  00000400  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  2 .eh_fram      00000038  00002000  00002000  00000600  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
```

and when i try to execute it, windows says "This app can't run in your PC"

Comment: Why are you using a linker script? Are you trying to write Windows programs or develop an Operating System? As for the actual error what happens if you use `ENTRY(_my_main)` instead of `ENTRY(_my_main)` . I've added an underscore to the beginning of my_main.

Comment: Your linker script is missing the important parts to make the program an executable for Windows. Please look into some of the provided ones.